# I can't install the zenplots package in R?

Tags: r, install.packages

I am having difficulty installing the `zenplots` package in R. For some odd reason when I use `install.packages('zenplots')` on my machine (Mac OS Catalina V-10.15.7) it installs fine... but when I try and install it on my second machine (also Mac OS Catalina V-10.15.7) and if I try and install it on my institutes server I get the following error:

> Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : couldn't connect to display ":0"
> Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘loon’:  .onLoad failed
> in loadNamespace() for 'loon', details:   call:
> structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj")   error: [tcl]
> couldn't connect to display ":0".
>
> Error: unable to load R code in package ‘zenplots’ Execution halted

I have also tried to install directly from GitHub using `remotes::install_github('great-northern-diver/zenplots', force = T)` but I get the same error as above.

I have even tried using `install.packages("zenplots", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` which works but unfortunatley this version doesn't contain all the functions found in `zenplots`.

My R version is above version 3.4.0, which is required for `zenplots` and as per the documentation I have already installed the `graph` package from BioConductor.

Any suggestions as to what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the R on your server was compiled without some feature required by the library. My guess: it is missing either `tcltk` or `X11` support. To check do the following:

```
capabilities()
```

And see which features return `FALSE`, meaning they are not enabled.

Comment: I ran `capabilities()` and 2 features returned as `FALSE` on the server (both returned `TRUE` on my machine where everything works fine)... they are `X11` and `aqua`. How do I go about adding these features?

Comment: Yeah, the error "couldn't connect to display" seems like it should be related to `X11`. First try connecting to the server with X11 forwarding. If you are doing ssh then do `ssh -Y`, and see if X11 starts working. Otherwise you will have to re-compile R with X11 support. But also keep in mind that I am not 100% sure that this is the main problem.